# Wrap text around image in HTML only

Tags: html, alignment

I am having trouble aligning text in HTML. There is a website that I am using and in one of the editable areas I have the ability to enter in a HTML snippet. We would like to have the text aligned in the middle, right hand side of the image. I can get the first line of text to align middle but the second line drops off under the image. Is there anyway to continue the text directly under the first line of text, while keeping it centered vertically. Unfortunately since this is a small HTML snippet I cannot add Div or CSS.

[image: We would want it to look something like this.]

We would want it to look something like the image attached above.

Thank you.

```html
<img style="padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;" float: left;" align="middle"src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Stop_hand_nuvola_alternate_text.svg"/><font color="#ff0000" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><font size="4"> Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here  <a href="https://blank.com/blank" target="_self">(a link)</a><a> Some more text here <a href="mailto:blank@blank.com">here is an email link</a> some more text.</p> </font>
```

Comment: Fix your typos please

Comment: I fixed it sorry

Comment: No, you fixed one and introduced another. It should be `style="padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px; float: left;"` which works by the way. Also note though that the `<font>` element no longer exists

Comment: Also, note that the `align` attribute is **deprecated** and should not be used and that `middle` has never been a valid value for `align` (although it was for `valign` before that was deprecated).

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know enough about code to know what the typos are. That is why I am asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your inline CSS code in the image:

You have: `<img style="padding:style="padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;" "float: left;"`
Should be: `<img style="padding:style="padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;float: left;"`

I removed: `" "`

```html
 <img style="padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;float: left;" align="middle"src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Stop_hand_nuvola_alternate_text.svg"/>
<font color="#ff0000" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><font size="4"> Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here Some Text here  <a href="https://blank.com/blank" target="_self">(a link)</a><a> Some more text here <a href="mailto:blank@blank.com">here is an email link</a> some more text.</p> </font>
```

Comment: This has already been noted in the comments above. You should, provided you have enough rep, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo.

Comment: Hmm, I see that it was added as a comment while I was writing this answer. (I got distracted while typing).

As for the voting, downvotes are counted but not displayed with my reputation, so it is hard to know the precise effect. Also, I am not allowed to comment since my reputation is below 50. But that is really offtopic here ;)